# Differences between two set of definitions of statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

What’s the difference between statistics as a science and statistics as a collection of facts and figures

Comment: What are you asking? What are these definitions?

Comment: The former is about methods of compiling and analysing data, and the latter is the data produced by those methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking this - or asking for this answer:

Statistics, as a field of mathematics (also called mathematical statistics), is the study of random events and how to model them.  More focused yet, there is the notion of '*a* statistic', which is a function of use in doing statistics.  For example the mean is a statistic, defined as the sum of points of data divided by the number of points.  But, note that 'a statistic' can be (and seem) a bit odd.  For example, if we want to make a statistical statement about the heights of people leaving an airplane, we can obviously use the mean to measure it.  But, we could also use just the height of the first person.  Surprisingly, this would be a perfectly good 'estimator', to use yet another term, in some ways.

I think your question part #2 relates to data collection.  For example, the US Bureau of labor statistics produces lots of data related to (as one example) unemployment through time.  There are endless libraries (offline and online) of statistics such as that.

Very often the tools and approaches of statistics, in the first sense, are applied to statistics in the latter sense.  And, loosely speaking, the study of how to apply those in the first sense to the data in the second sense is called the study of statistics.